# Using a button to rotate images App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm just getting started with App Maker.

I need users to be able to upload an image (this we can do) and then ROTATE the image by clicking a button below it.

I can't find the correct code write in Custom Action in the onClick section in Property editor

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [client script](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client) and add your function to the onClick event. To give you an idea, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cqPA.gif), try:

On a Client Script, create variables for your page and its descendant (children) elements:

```
var pgImage = app.pages.UploadImage;
var pgImageDesc = pgImage.descendants;
```

Here your function. Let's say your users are uploading the image in a panel named `PanelImage`.

```
function rotateImage() {

  var image = pgImageDesc.PanelImage;
  image.styles = ['rotated'];

}
```

You declare the CSS class "rotated" in the **[Style Editor](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/css)**. If you want to apply it to the page only, add it to the **Page style** section. If it's a global class, add it to **Global style**:

```
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(180deg); /* Equal to rotateZ(180deg) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? You could use CSS/javascript to rotate the image displayed, but that won't change the file itself. Is your intention to change the file?